# How to read numbers from stdin until end

Tags: c, unix, stdin

Where there is `for(;;)` I need something to read from stdin and save to `N`.
Something with `read(stdin,N,sizeof(float))` and `while(s!=EOF)` `s=getc(stdin)` maybe?  *I'm assuming a list of numbers is saved on stdin separated end of lines*

The question was something like:

> Your program must print its pid to standard output. Then it should start to read values of N from standard input until the end of the file. After receiving a signal (SIGUSR1) your program should subtract (then multiply, then divide, then subtract) the value of N from sum (first value of sum=0) as a cycle. After receiving SIGUSR2 your program should print the current sum.

How I interpreted the question and attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

float N,sum=0;
int count=0;

void handler(int s){
    count++;
    if (s==SIGUSR1){
        if (count==1){
            sum-=N;
        }   
        if (count==2){
            sum*=N;
        }
        if (count==3){
            sum/=N;
        }
        if (count==4){
            sum+=N;
            count==0;
        }

    }

    else if (s==SIGUSR2){
        printf("sum=%d",sum);
    }
}


int main(){
    pid_t pid=getpid();
    signal(SIGUSR1,handler);
    signal(SIGUSR2,handler);
    printf("%d",pid);
    fflush(stdout); 

    for(;;)
    scanf("%d",&N);


    return(0);
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. What's your question, exactly? It looks like you figured everything out already. Is there something wrong with the `scanf` call you have? My only suggestion is to add newlines (`\n`) to each of your `printf` calls.

Comment: The program showed a "Wall time-limit exceeded" on their checker. So how can I break the 'for' loop when it's EOF (of stdin) ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the return value of `scanf`. It returns the number of items successfully matched, so if it doesn't return 1 then you're done.

```
while (scanf("%d", &N) == 1)
    ;
```

Comment: maybe `while (scanf("%d", &N) !=EOF)` is better?

Comment: and does this do the same: `while( feof(stdin)!=EOF) (scanf("%d", &N);` ?